# Guard crashing Spork when using guard-spork

Tags: ruby, rspec, spork, guard

**I've followd the ["How I Test" screencast at RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test), however I ran into a problem with spork**

```
$ guard
Guard is now watching at '/Users/darth/projects/auth-before'
Starting Spork for Test::Unit & RSpec 
Couldn't find a supported test framework that begins with 'testunit'

Supported test frameworks:
( ) Cucumber
(*) RSpec

Legend: ( ) - not detected in project   (*) - detected
Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
ERROR: Could not start Spork server for Test::Unit & RSpec. Make sure you can use it manually first.

# here I get growl notification "Test::Unit & RSpec NOT started

Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
Running tests with args ["--color", "--format", "progress", "--format", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter::NotificationRSpec", "--out", "/dev/null", "--require", "/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-rspec-0.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatters/notification_rspec.rb", "spec"]...
.

Finished in 14.47 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
Done.
```

When I try to run `spork` in a separate terminal window, it doesn't help, as it gets killed instantly once I run `guard`

```
$ spork
Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
Killed: 9
```

If I just run `spork` and then try `rspec . --drb`, it works just fine. **[Here's link to gist](https://gist.github.com/1301161) with my Gemfile, Guardfile and spec_helper.rb**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is actually caused by `guard` killing `spork` before it can even load, which is a problem on my *slower* MacBook pro.

The solution is to increase the wait time with `:wait => 120` in the `Guardfile`, e.g.

```
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, 
               :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :wait => 120
    ....
```

Answer (score 10):

You should change:

```
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, 
               :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, 
               :wait => 120
```

to:

```
guard 'spork', :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, 
                cucumber: false, 
                test_unit: false
```

Comment: taivn07 and Kevin Bedell's solution worked better than Jakub's for me. Increasing the wait time dind't solve the problem. Disabling Cucumber and TestUnit solved it.

Comment: To use minitest without rspec, change the `:rspec_env` bit to `:rspec => false` and add `:minitest_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }`